# IE9: childNodes not updated after splitText?

Tags: dom, internet-explorer-9

On Internet Explorer 9, calling `splitText` on a text node doesn't update the `childNodes` of its parent. On Chrome and Firefox it does, as expected per https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Text.splitText .

**However** IE9 does behave properly when `console.dir` is called on the text node parent (?)

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

window.onload = function() {

  var e = document.querySelector('#test p');

  var f = e.childNodes[0].splitText(10);

  console.log(e.childNodes.length)

  // console.dir(e)

  console.log(e.childNodes.length)

}

</script>

<div id="test">
  <p>Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>

</html>
```

IE9 outputs:

```
LOG: 1
LOG: 1
```

Chrome and Firefox both correctly output:

```
2
2
```

When uncommenting `console.dir(e)`, now IE9 outputs:

```
LOG: 1
LOG: [object HTMLParagraphElement] {}
LOG: 2
```

Is this a bug? If so, is there any workaround to "refresh" and reflect the actual state of `childNodes`, besides `console.dir`?

**Update** What appears to work at the moment is adding/removing a node, like:

```
var t = document.createTextNode("");
e.appendChild(t);
e.removeChild(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a workaround instead of `splitText()`:

```
function insertAfter(node, precedingNode) {
    var nextNode = precedingNode.nextSibling, parent = precedingNode.parentNode;
    if (nextNode) {
        parent.insertBefore(node, nextNode);
    } else {
        parent.appendChild(node);
    }
    return node;
}

// Note that we cannot use splitText() because it is bugridden in IE 9.
function splitDataNode(node, index) {
    var newNode = node.cloneNode(false);
    newNode.deleteData(0, index);
    node.deleteData(index, node.length - index);
    insertAfter(newNode, node);
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using my workaround which seems to work fine, with no noticeable performance penalty.